# Running multiple Tasks from button click (UI thread) - how to know if they all succeeded or some failed?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I have WPF application where in a button click handler I want to start multiple tasks (where each may perform a long running operation).

I want to report to the user whether all tasks succeeded, or if not, what the error(s) were of the individual tasks.

I can't see a nice way though of distinguishing between at least one exception or all succeeding.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace WPFTaskApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Task t1 = new Task(DoSomething);
            Task t2 = new Task(DoSomethingElse);

            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();

            // So now both tasks are running.
            // I want to display one of two messages to the user:
            // If both tasks completed ok, as in without exceptions, then notify the user of the success
            // If an exception occured in either task notify the user of the exception.

            // The closest I have got to the above is to use ContinueWhenAll, but this doesn't let
            // me filter on the completion type

            Task[] tasks = { t1, t2 };

            Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, f =>
                {
                    // This is called when both tasks are complete, but is called
                    // regardless of whether exceptions occured.
                    MessageBox.Show("All tasks completed");
                });
        }

        private void DoSomething()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Debug.WriteLine("DoSomething complete.");
        }

        private void DoSomethingElse()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your continuation, you can check each task for an exception:

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, f =>
            {
                if (t1.Exception != null)
                {
                     // t1 had an exception
                }
                if (t2.Exception != null)
                {
                     // t2 had an exception
                }

                // This is called when both tasks are complete, but is called
                // regardless of whether exceptions occured.
                MessageBox.Show("All tasks completed");
            });
```

Comment: Note that `f` is the array of `Task`s, also.  So you could use that rather than closing over `tasks`.

Comment: @MattSmith Yeah, but it's a bit more difficult to know, off hand, which one is which.  Closing over them makes that obvious, which is why I wrote it this way.